# Variable "inputVariable" does not have a part named "payload"

Tags: oracle, soa, bpel

I am trying to deploy a composite I created in JDeveloper 12.1.3.0.0 to Weblogic 12.1.3.0.0. When I deploy from JDeveloper I get the following message on deployment.

```
[01:17:00 PM] Error deploying archive sca_MX_StormCreateUpdatePlantAcctWO_ABCS_req_rev1.0.jar to partition "WorkOrderServices" on server WLS_SOA1 [https://myip:8002] 
[01:17:00 PM] HTTP error code returned [500]
[01:17:00 PM] Error message from server:
There was an error deploying the composite on WLS_SOA1: Deployment Failed: Error occurred during deployment of component: MX_StormCreateUpdatePlantAcctWO_ABCS_req to service engine: implementation.bpel, for composite: MX_StormCreateUpdatePlantAcctWO_ABCS_req: ORABPEL-05215

Error while loading process.
The process domain is encountering the following errors while loading the process "MX_StormCreateUpdatePlantAcctWO_ABCS_req" (composite "WorkOrderServices/MX_StormCreateUpdatePlantAcctWO_ABCS_req!1.0*soa_7dc4d4f8-7df0-465a-9d11-e7c1d8cb9c2d"): Validation of BPEL2.0 process failed..
This error contained an exception thrown by the underlying process loader module.
Check the exception trace in the log (with logging level set to debug mode). If there is a patch installed on the server, verify that the bpelcClasspath domain property includes the patch classes.
.

[01:17:00 PM] Check server log for more details.
[01:17:00 PM] Error deploying archive sca_MX_StormCreateUpdatePlantAcctWO_ABCS_req_rev1.0.jar to partition "WorkOrderServices" on server WLS_SOA1 [https://myip:8002] 
[01:17:00 PM] Deployment cancelled.
[01:17:00 PM] ----  Deployment incomplete  ----.
[01:17:00 PM] Error deploying archive file:/WorkOrder_EBS/MX_StormCreateUpdatePlantAcctWO_ABCS_req/deploy/sca_MX_StormCreateUpdatePlantAcctWO_ABCS_req_rev1.0.jar 
 (oracle.tip.tools.ide.fabric.deploy.common.SOARemoteDeployer)
```

This composite compiles fine in JDeveloper. In the WLS_SOA1-diagnostic.log I am seeing these errors.

```
[2016-06-13T13:16:57.542-05:00] [WLS_SOA1] [ERROR] [] [oracle.soa.bpel.engine.compiler] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: TX12238] [ecid: 921f7c10-6914-4003-96f8-df103a09a69a-0005c140,0] [APP: soa-infra] [DSID: 0000LLAykDqB1FELJ6U4Uf1NMlsk00007u] Validation of BPEL2.0 process failed.
[2016-06-13T13:16:57.542-05:00] [WLS_SOA1] [ERROR] [] [oracle.soa.bpel.engine.compiler] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: TX12238] [ecid: 921f7c10-6914-4003-96f8-df103a09a69a-0005c140,0] [APP: soa-infra] [DSID: 0000LLAykDqB1FELJ6U4Uf1NMlsk00007u] BPEL/MX_StormCreateUpdatePlantAcctWO_ABCS_req.bpel:71 error "element" is set to "ns3:LogEvent" on this <bpel:variable>  but it cannot be resolved (check value of "element", imports, WSDLs or XSDs)., Suggested Fix : Make sure that value "ns3:LogEvent" is resolvable (check imports, value of "element").
[2016-06-13T13:16:57.543-05:00] [WLS_SOA1] [ERROR] [] [oracle.soa.bpel.engine.compiler] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: TX12238] [ecid: 921f7c10-6914-4003-96f8-df103a09a69a-0005c140,0] [APP: soa-infra] [DSID: 0000LLAykDqB1FELJ6U4Uf1NMlsk00007u] BPEL/MX_StormCreateUpdatePlantAcctWO_ABCS_req.bpel:81 error Variable "inputVariable" does not have a part named "payload" - check expression segment "$inputVariable.payload"
```

I have ran into similar ORABPEL-05215 errors before and resolved them by updating my MDS. I updated all the MDS files that this composite references.  I have re-created the inputVariable to try to resolve this error message with no luck.

Comment: You should not add your IP addresses in a public site.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder @JorgeCampos

Answer (score 0):

I was able to deploy after removing this file WorkOrderRouter_ep.wsdl and its reference in the composite.xml. After looking in the logs the WLS_SOA1-diagnostic.log had multiple entries for not being able to find XSD files that were not necessary to this composite. Turns out this WSDL was referencing them.